# Loging in to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
My username: pizza_username
My password: password
Server: [I think this is the problem] localhost
```

> Error: 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I tried on my cousins computer (hes the hoster) and everything worked. How do i make it work for my comp 2?

Comment: Enable remote connection and set the host address to be the local ip of the machine where it's hosted

Comment: use his ip address, instead of localhost, please don't post credentials though.  so it would be the network ip address ( like 169. something I think ) of that machine if on a local network or the IP if on the web.  Local host means this host ( machine )

Comment: yeah pizza.username was just an example

Answer (score 0):

1. First, see if you can route from your computer to the remote host:  `nc -vz remote.host 3306` (substitute `remote.host` for the IP address or domain name of the MySQL server).  If this does not report back that it `succeeded!`, you have a network problem to resolve first.  The `nc` network utility (netcat) may need to be installed on your computer to do this step.
2. Make sure the user account you are trying to use has granted your user account permissions to access the database *from the host you're using.*  For example, if your users table has an access entry for `pizza_username@localhost` account, it can access the database only from the localhost (ie, the computer the server is running on).  `pizza_username@localhost` is not the equivalent to `pizza_username@123.456.789.101` or `@`at some other host.   The host in the user account database must match the host you're connecting from.  At the end of the day, it's a completely different user account with completely different access privileges.

Comment: `telnet {remote IP} 3306` is easier than the above.